# Custom button only functioning at first element in the HTML list

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am creating a Django HTML template that contains a list and each list is supposed to have a custom button, as many list elements that exist there must be a custom button for it. This button is supposed to toggle between active and inactive. After creating this toggle using JavaScript, it only works for the first element of the list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dashboard</title>

     {% load static %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
     <script src="{% static 'js/dashboard.js' %}">
     </script>
</head>
<body>

   
   {% for all_users in users %}     
    <li>{{all_users}}
        
         <button onclick="handleToggle()" id="switchName" type="submit"> Switch To Active State
        </button>
        
    </li>  
    {% endfor %}

<p> this is all {{users}}</p>
    <p>there are {{usersCount}} users in the admin and its presently {{now}}</p>

    <form method="get">
      {{filterUsers.form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
     </form>
     <ul>
        {% for user in filterUsers.qs %}
          <li>{{user}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My corresponding JavaScript looks like

```
function handleToggle() 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("switchName");
    if (elem.innerHTML=="Switch To Active State") 
    elem.innerHTML = "Switch To Inactive State";
    else elem.innerHTML = "Switch To Active State";
}

PLease any suggestions and corrections are veery much welcom
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handleToggle() 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("switchName");
    if (elem.innerHTML=="Switch To Active State") {
      elem.innerHTML = "Switch To Inactive State";
    }
    else {
      elem.innerHTML = "Switch To Active State";  
    }
}
```

You need to have brackets! Try this